# Why does my Android studio preview look different?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm wondering why in every tutorial I watch the preview section looks like this: i.e it has the actual device shown as preview and has a button for linking it to an activity 
[image]

When mine looks like this: for some reason doesn't have the device
[image]

I'm sure I've just not installed something correctly or not clicked a checkbox, or a version of something is wrong but after some googling i can't seem to work out what it is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newer versions of Android Studio do not show the device bezel by default. Everything looks installed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Android Studio window title.

Your video is using 2.0 Beta, and your newer version just doesn't have the bezel.

You'll also notice there's different buttons around the screen preview area.

You could disable it in older versions, I'm not sure if it's completely gone but it was probably removed because it took up screen space and didn't serve much purpose